# In MS Excel, How can I create a dynamic date range using Data Validation?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

[image]

Hi guys.

In the image above, I want to create a dynamic drop down list for each subsequent cells in column K to show the date range selection from 1 to the last date in the month of the respective column B. For example, the drop down list of K3 should show `1-Aug-22` to `31-Aug-22`.

How should I define the formula in this case?

To find a right formula to solve my excel problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a dynamic list for data validation must be based on an actual worksheet range; it cannot be generated solely *in-formula*.

Assuming you use cell `Z2` for the first (horizontal) list, enter this formula in that cell:

```
=LET(
    ζ, EOMONTH(B2, -1) + 1,
    ξ, EOMONTH(B2, 0),
    SEQUENCE(, ξ - ζ + 1, ζ)
)
```

then copy down as required.

The data validation for cell `K2` would then be the *List* option with the following formula:

```
=Z2#
```

Copy this validation down as required.